# Optimize Sequelize query for large PostgreSQL dataset in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a Node.js application using Sequelize as the ORM to interact with a PostgreSQL database. One of my queries retrieves data from a table that can have millions of records and has around 15-20 columns. The query fetches data based on a date range and optional filters am using rawSQL query. Here is the code for the query function:

kindly guide me thanks

here is my code

```
exports.getactivationData = async function (params, pagination = true) {
    try {
        
        let dbModels = await db.Models();

        let query = `SELECT * FROM my_large_table WHERE date("createdAt") BETWEEN '${params.startDate}' AND '${params.endDate}'`;

        if (!pagination) {
            query = `SELECT count(*) FROM my_large_table WHERE date("createdAt") BETWEEN '${params.startDate}' AND '${params.endDate}'`;
        }

        if (params.filter1) {
            query += ` AND sensitive_column_id = '${params.sensitiveFilterId}'`;
        }

        if (params.filter2) {
            query += ` AND sensitive_column_value = '${params.sensitiveFilterValue}'`;
        }

        if (pagination && params.limit) {
            query += ` ORDER BY "${params.sortBy}" ${params.sortType} `;
            query += ` LIMIT '${params.limit}' OFFSET '${params.offset}'`;
        }

        const myLargeTableData = await db.sequelize.query(query, {
            model: dbModels.myLargetableModel
        });

        return promiseAdapter.resolve(myLargeTableData);
    } catch (error) {
        return promiseAdapter.reject(error);
    }
}
```

I'm concerned about the performance of this query, especially when dealing with large datasets (e.g., fetching 10 hours of data results in around 62k records). How can I optimize this Sequelize query to improve its performance when querying a large PostgreSQL table?

Additionally, in my controller, I call this function like so:

```
let data = await reportmodel.getactivationData (params);
// For count
let resultCount = await reportmodel.getactivationData (params, false);
```

**Note: I want to optimize as above takes time for almost 30-40 seconds even with limit of 10 records as by default I am using limit = 10. Still its taking much time**

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statement? And the ddl for all tables and indexes involved. All in plain text

Comment: It is going to be hard to optimize every permutation of that code.  Please focus on a single query (text) you most want to be made faster, and give the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for it. Turn on track_io_timing if it is not already on.

Comment: If you use raw SQL queries and small amount of requested records than it's nothing about Sequelize. Try to optimize queries outside the code. Pay attention to `createdAt` column index and casting to a date (maybe it's better to pass the beginning and the end of the day instead of casting). Anyway without detailed SQL query plan we can't guide you farther